# Auto-jump on today's date upon upening the spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I use a spreadsheet with a date in a row per column. I would like to have the sheet open on the current date when opening. How can I make this?

Comment: Carl, dit is een Engelse site. Kun je je tekst [edit]en naar Engels? Overigens snap ik je vraag niet. Wat is 'in een rij per kolom een datum staat'? Geef eens concrete voorbeelden van cellen met hun inhoud; en beter nog: ook een link naar een gedeelde voorbeeld sheet.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Only Row 3 has dates in the collums.

Comment: In every collum is a date, Each next collum has the following date. The others rows have information belonging to that date.

Answer (score 0):

- this script checks the **1**st row of **Sheet1** for dates and jumps to today's date when present

  ```
  function onOpen() {
  var s, d, c;
  s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  d=new Date();
  d.setHours(0);d.setMinutes(0);d.setSeconds(0);
  c=Math.round((d-s.getRange(1,2).getValue())/86400000)+2;
  s.getRange(1, c).activate();
  }
  ```